# Can't set binlog_format for MariaDB

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I have MariaDB running on my dev server (no replication or anything else) running version 5.3.5. It's an Ubuntu 10.04 server running all the latest patches and updates.  I am having issued getting errors regarding the the binlog_format, so I went to change it from STATEMENT to MIXED or ROW, but when I run `SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED'`, nothing gets updated. I have tried everything from this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/what-is-the-safest-way-to-switch-the-binlog-format-at-runtime, but nothing changes.  The only way I have gotten it to change is with the following:

```
sudo service stop mysql
sudo mysqld --binlog_format=MIXED
```

The only problem is that when I restart the format goes back to statement based.  Is there anything else I am supposed to do to change it as a global variable?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the problem by adding `binlog_format = MIXED` to my my.cnf file.  I hadn't tried that before, because I didn't see it setting the format there, but when I added it near all of the other binlog settings and restarted the service, it worked.